# Single word for "loan return"

Tags: single-word-requests

The example used in my firm is just called "loan return" (when someone gets payed back on their loan) but I was wondering if there is a single-word replacement for "loan return". Also a sub question I have is it more correct to say "single word" or "single-word"

Comment: Since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used. You should also only have just one question.

Comment: "single word" vs "single-word" depends on how you're using the phrase.  A "single-word replacement" is a replacement that is a single word.  A single word replacement is a word replacement that is single (it could be a phrase).

Comment: Are you looking for "reimbursement"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Repayment** refers to a single payment on a loan; if you're talking about the loan being paid off entirely, then the phrase **paid in full** or **paid off** is customary.